# why does copy event handler get triggered multiple times for a single copy event in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set up copy event listener and handler but am getting `copy detected...` logged 5 times instead of once per copy event.  I was wondering how I can avoid this.

```
function App() {
  const onCopy = e => {
    console.log('copy detected...')
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('copy', onCopy);
    return () =>{
      document.removeEventListener('copy', onCopy);
    }
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a minimal reproduce example on codesanbox.io?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with your code https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-framework-zrxv0

Comment: My observation is, (at my end) for the very first time it is printing only once but when I refresh the page it is printing multiple time.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but I'm not seeing this behavior anymore. thanks for confirming!